# specific cell deletion in multiple row excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Please picture a table composed of triplicate rows:

- rows n, n+1 and n+2 are identical
- rows n+3, n+4 and n+5 are identical
- and so on

could you please help me with the codes to do the following:

- clear the content of the cells in column Q and R in row n
- clear the content of the cells in column P and R in row n+1
- clear the content of the cells in column P and Q in row n+2
- Repeat for all the other groups of 3 rows until the end

Thank you for your help

Thx Flex for your suggestion of showing what I did so far. I tried many things with my limited knowledge get to that last part done w/o success. The other steps I've worked on are here:

```
    Sub Macro11()
'
' Macro11 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+k
'
Dim myCell
Set myCell = ActiveCell

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    myCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Set myCell = ActiveCell
Wend
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Numeric Identifier"
    Range("C12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Department"
    Range("D12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Category"
    Range("A11:A12,B11:B12,C11:C12,D11:D12").Select
    Range("D12").Activate
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
        Range("E1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B13").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C13").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D13").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Here is the latest I tried:

```
Sub Macro13()
'
' Macro13 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
Dim myCell
Set myCell = ActiveCell
Do
 Range("Q").Value = 0
 Range("R").Value = 0

myCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Set myCell = ActiveCell

 Range("P").Value = 0
 Range("R").Value = 0
 
myCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Set myCell = ActiveCell

 Range("P").Value = 0
 Range("Q").Value = 0
 
myCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Set myCell = ActiveCell
Loop
Wend


End Sub
```

Again => trial and error here. Never had time to learn properly how to do vba

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Can you share what you've tried so far? I think people will be more willing to help if you can show you've made an effort on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. Please read the comments and adjust as necessary.

Top tip to learn here is that `For` loops can have a `Step` argument included.

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub ClearCells()


Dim lastRow As Integer

Dim i As Integer

Dim r As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'use this if every row has a value in column A
lastRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'OR use this to just specify the last row with data (if you prefer)
'lastRow = 10

'Change the starting row of your data by changing A2 to whatever is the top-left cell you have data in
'also change the Z to the right-most column you have data in
Set r = ws.Range("A2:Z" & lastRow)

'loop through each set of three rows in the range
For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count Step 3

 With r
    'clear Q and R
    .Cells(i, 17).ClearContents
    .Cells(i, 18).ClearContents
    
    'clear P and R on i + 1
    .Cells(i + 1, 16).ClearContents
    .Cells(i + 1, 18).ClearContents
    
    'clear P and Q on i + 2
    .Cells(i + 2, 16).ClearContents
    .Cells(i + 2, 17).ClearContents
    
 End With

Next i 'steps three rows down

MsgBox "Finished clearing cells"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply (sorry i do not see your name). I'll be back at work next Tuesday and will try your suggestion. Thx a ton for taking the time to answering my question

Answer (score 0):

thank you again for your code: very helpful.
I have played with it this morning and changed areas you suggested needed to be fitted to my spreadsheet.
Here is how it looks now:[image]

The top 2 lines are from the previous macro.
I have 2 questions:

1. I am not familiar with the "option explicit" command your suggested macro started with, but each time I put it at the beginning of your macro, that line of code ends up moving to the end of the previous macro: is this normal?
2. As you can see, I associated running your Macro with the "Ctrl+q" keystroke: for some reason this doesn't work (always worked with my other macro) BUT if I open the macro editor and "run" the macro from there => it's doing a perfect job => thank you already for this sir/madam !

Thank you very much for having taken the time to helping me.
Cheers